# Iterating over pandas dataframe and saving into separate sheets in xlxs file

Tags: excel, pandas

I'm iterating over a pandas dataframe during and carry out and operation to obtain the information (excel sheet number) for saving the appropriate excel sheet like this:

```
from opnepyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

for i,data in df.iterows:
    sheet=data['SheetNo']

    #Create excel writer
    writer=pd.Excelwriter('output.xlxs')

    # write dataframe to excelsheet
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet)

    #save the excel file
    writer.save()
```

Dataframe:

```
ID  SheetNo setting
2304    2   IGV5
2305    3   IGV2
2306    1   IGV6
2307    2   IGV2
2308    1   IGV1
```

What I wanted was for data to go into each of the created 'SheetNo' of the excel file, instead the the previous sheet is being overwritten by the following one, and you can only see the last sheet number.

What can I do to make this code work? Any other approach apart from mine above will be welcome.

Comment: Hi @Rob - Are you trying to write each row into a separate sheet within `output.xlsx`? If yes, you have repeated `SheetNo` for 1 and 2. Should that not be unique?

Comment: Hi @Redox, my idea was to use "sheet=data['SheetNo']" to obtain unique sheet no for each row.

Comment: Correct, but data['SheetNo'] = 2 for the 1st and 4th rows. Are you ok that the 4th iteration overwrites the data written in the first iteration? Based on your logic, won't there just be 3 tab/worksheets 1,2,3?

Comment: What the code was meant to do is to add data to the appropriate sheet in the excel file, e.g., data in rows 1 and 4 should go into sheet no 2 (appended), and  data in rows 3 and 5 should go into sheet no 1 (appended). I'm sure my approach may be wrong. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the python code is below. Note that:

1. Assumption is that there is already an `output.xlsx` file in same dir that this code runs
2. It will search for worksheet names with the `SheetNo` column. If not available in the file, it will create a new worksheet/tab with that name and add the header row
   3.The program will then add each row (append) to the sheet
3. Once all data in DF is added, it will save file back to same name
4. You can run this as many times as you want, it will keep adding new sheets or appending to existing sheets.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data = {'ID': [2304,2305,2306,2307,2308],
'SheetNo': [2,3,1,2,1],
'setting': ['IGV5', 'IGV2', 'IGV6', 'IGV2', 'IGV1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
headers = ['ID','SheetNo','setting']

FilePath = 'output.xlsx' #ASSUMPTON - File already exists
wb = load_workbook(FilePath)

for sheet in df.SheetNo.unique(): 
    if str(sheet) in wb.sheetnames: #If sheet in excel file
        ws = wb[str(sheet)]
    else:
        ws = wb.create_sheet(title=str(sheet)) #Create New sheet is not present
        ws.append(headers) #New sheet = Need header, else not required
    i =0
    j = 0
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws.max_row+1, max_row=ws.max_row+len(df[df.SheetNo == sheet]), min_col=1, max_col=3):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = df[df.SheetNo == sheet].iloc[i,j]
            j = j + 1
        j=0
        i= i + 1
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

**Output excel after one run of the code**

[image]

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your help @Redox. I really apreciate it!